# RxJs noop and Identity functions

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am learning RxJs now days and came accross following two functions which are part of thier helper library

```
Rx.helpers.identity(x)
```

and

```
Rx.helpers.noop()
```

[According to the RxJs Helpers documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/helpers/readme.md)
for Rx.helpers.identity(x), the documentation says that this is a function which just returns the value that is passed into it unmodified. For Rx.helpers.noop, they say this function really does nothing.

Q: What is the purpose to provide these functions and in which scenario it is useful to use these functions?

Comment: Usage of them is not specific for `RxJS`. 

They are handy in different context when composing functions.

Having single place of definition saves some space on heap; but in most contexts ad-hoc created functions are good enough.

Answer (score 1):

One of the common use cases where I use identity is when I have to "unwrap" contents of an observable coming from a different library/API, e.g.:

```
names$ // Observable<Observable<string>> 
  .flatMap( Rx.helpers.identity )// Observable<string>
  .subscribe( (name: string) => console.log(name) )
```

These functions become even more helpful when dealing with a stream of functions, which is a fairly common practice in FRP ([redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) would be the most obvious example), where effectively your actions are mapped to functions taking your previous state and returning the new one.

What's more interesting is that `noop` and `identity` can serve a very similar purpose, depending on your data being immutable or not.

[Edit] Usually you can replace `observable.flatMap( identity )` with the `switch` operator, as in:  `observable.switch()`.